# Extracting ltpa token from with portlet

Tags: javascript, websphere-portal

I have configured `SSO` using `LTPA` between `Websphere Portal` and `Websphere Commerce` and this is working fine.

I have a `HTML` portlet (`Web Content Viewer` based) with the following javascript ..

```
<script>
alert(getCookie('LtpaToken2'));
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  alert(document.cookie);
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
</script>
```

How come `LTPA` token is not present? Even though I can see it in the web console (network view)

The sequence of `alerts` show:

1. ```
   DigestTracker=AAABSalkR30; 
   UnicaNIODID=LoLHPvCDf0C-Y2rOEEq; 
   mmid=162538914%7CMgAAAAr4jptRGwsAAA%3D%3D; 
   mmcore.pd=-1067100437%7CMgAAAAoBQviOm1EbC8RXPI0TAK+d8VIRy9FIAA0AAADOVKqv/bXRSAAAAAD/////AP//////////AAZEaXJlY3QBLwsJAAAACgABAAAAAAD///////////////8AAAAAAAFF;
   mmcore.srv=ldnvwcgus01; 
   IBM_W3SSO_ACCESS=w3-03.sso.ibm.com; ibmSurvey=1428952756135; 
   CoreM_State=19~-1~-1~-1~-1~3~3~5~3~3~7~7~|~~|~~|~~|~||||||~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~;
   CoreM_State_Content=6~|~~|~|; 
   cookie_country_4LF=us; 
   mmcore.tst=0.676; 
   CoreID6=43553851578714150993122&ci=50200000|IBMTESTWWW_51040000|IBMTESTW3
   ```
2. `undefined`

Comment: I am not sure, but it may be httpOnly cookie https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Georgy mentioned, the cookie was set to `HTTPOnly` in `WAS`, which could be disabled under the `Security` settings.